# VBA TransferSpreadsheet Import Problems

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have an excel template that is used by ~ 12 people to complete daily work.  When they are finished, there is a "submit" button that transmits a range of cells using 3 hidden worksheets into a specific database for that user.

I'm using the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet Ac Import to import the cell ranges into that particular user's database (stored on a network drive) using the code below:

```
Dim acc As New Access.Application
Dim AnalystDB As String

AnalystDB = Worksheets("Quality Form").Range("I4").Value

acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "Z:\Production\Daily_Work\" & AnalystDB & ".accdb"

acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:="tblSummary", _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:="tblSummary$A:O"

acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:="tblAccount", _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:="tblAccounts$A:D"

acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
            TransferType:=acImport, _
            SpreadSheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
            TableName:="tblErrors", _
            Filename:=Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
            HasFieldNames:=True, _
            Range:="tblErrors$C:I"

    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    Set acc = Nothing
```

My problem is that each day I can see approx. 30+ correct submission records, but invariably 3-5 are missing an end-time value.

For Example I will see a record like this:

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      ID             |     STARTTIME    |      ENDTIME     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      15978458       | 5/30/18 10:15 AM |                  |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

Each database file/tables are all exact copies of one another and I was extremely thorough to match all the data types/formats between the excel worksheets and table fields.

I cannot identify what is causing the end time value to not import.  I do not see a table for any import errors, and typically if the import is unsuccessful then the entire record is missing, not just 1 value in the table.

Just a few other key points:  The value that is always missing is a "endtime" which is a timestamp of when the submit button was clicked.  When I go to the worksheet I can see the End date/time in the cell.  Also, some users are running the template in one instance of excel, but have another instance open so they can view other files/reference material.  I'm beginning to wonder if the multiple instances could cause the import to end prematurely somehow.  I'm also wondering if latency with the network drive could cause this issue.  Since this error is occurring intermittently I'm perplexed as to what scenario is causing this.  I would appreciate any feedback or suggestions on how to correct this problem.

Comment: Could easily be due to a date type problem in either Excel and/or Access. Anyway, see this: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=239492

Comment: You could try to add some validating of the record before saving and closing the worksheet.

Comment: Where is the submit code that fills in the timestamp fields? Do you save the workbook before transferring?

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the saving topic.  So when the submit procedure runs, it transfers everything to the DB, then returns the user to the workbook, makes a few more changes to the file then saves the workbook.  Maybe adding in a save prior to the data transfer step will help.